# Getting the value of OpenSavePidlMRU in the registry

Tags: c++, winapi

I'm trying to get the last opened directory by an open file dialog, and it seems that we can get it by first retrieving the key's name that contains the path using the first BYTE of the MRUListEx key, then the path can be obtained by reading the value of this key's name.
MRUListEx key can be find at: `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\ComDlg32\LastVisitedPidlMRU`.
The problem is that I don't know how to properly fill the "SHITEMID" structure. (it doesn't let me access the index, and it throws a Memory access violation). I don't even know if the code below is valid in any points.

*Sorry, the code is very dirty for the moment but I'll revamps it when I finally find what causes these errors.*

```cpp
void MyClass::OnDocumentSave(bool showSaveDlg)
{
        // Do something that is not relevant here... 

        try {
        HKEY hKey = NULL;
        std::wstring regPath = LR"(Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\ComDlg32\LastVisitedPidlMRU\)";
        LSTATUS statusCode = RegOpenKeyExW(HKEY_CURRENT_USER, regPath.data(), 0, KEY_QUERY_VALUE, &hKey);
        
         if (statusCode != ERROR_SUCCESS)
            throw std::exception(std::string("Unable to open the specified registry key, sys err code: ") + std::to_string(statusCode));
        
        BYTE data[MAX_PATH];
        DWORD bufferSize = MAX_PATH;
        statusCode = RegGetValueW(hKey, L"", L"MRUListEx", RRF_RT_REG_BINARY, NULL, &data, &bufferSize);
        
        if (statusCode != ERROR_SUCCESS)
            throw std::runtime_error(std::string("Failed at RegGetValue() Sys error code: ") + std::to_string(statusCode));
        
        // Please note that the buffer has intentionally a fixed size here and everything is
        // simplified for readability, but it uses dynamic memory allocation in the real code to
        // handle errors such as ERROR_MORE_DATA
        BYTE* pathData[512];
        bufferSize = 512;
        DWORD type = 0; // In case it matters, the returned value is 3
        statusCode = RegGetValueW(hKey, L"", std::to_wstring(data[0]).c_str(), RRF_RT_REG_BINARY, &type, &pathData, &bufferSize);
        
        if (statusCode != ERROR_SUCCESS)
            throw std::runtime_error(std::string("Failed at RegGetValue() Sys error code: ") + std::to_string(statusCode));
        
        // I don't know how to fill this structure, the documentation is very minimal,
        // and I don't understand it.
        int offset = sizeof(APPNAME);
        SHITEMID shellIDList[2]{
            // Throw a memory access violation at 0x*****, the debugger can't seems to 
            // get anything in pathData.
            { sizeof(USHORT) + sizeof(pathData), *pathData[0 + offset] },
            { 0, 0 } };
        ITEMIDLIST idl{ shellIDList[0] };

        // This is supposed give me the last path that was opened by a File Picker.
        SHGetPathFromIDListW(&idl, initialDir.data());
    }
    catch (std::exception& e) {
        // Silently set the initial directory to a hard-coded path instead of getting the registry value.
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't know what the ultimate goal here is, though I'm having a feeling that you're reinventing the wheel. The [`IFileDialog`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/shobjidl_core/nn-shobjidl_core-ifiledialog) interface monitors this state information for you already. [`IFileDialog::SetClientGuid`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/shobjidl_core/nf-shobjidl_core-ifiledialog-setclientguid) is your opportunity to select a store based on arbitrary criteria (e.g. per app, or per file type).

Comment: See [The SetClientGuid method of the common file and folder dialogs lets you give names to those dialogs, too](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20200527-00/?p=103801) for rationale that's missing from the official documentation.

Comment: I've rolled back your edit. It is not acceptable here to add the solution you've found to the question. If you found a solution you want to share, do so by writing an answer to the question in the space provided below for that purpose, as described in [Can I answer my own question?](http://www.stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer)

Answer (score 0):

You don't seem to understand how types and simple arrays work! `BYTE* pathData[512];` is not a 512 byte buffer. Use `BYTE pathData[512];`.

After reading into `pathData`, call `SHGetPathFromIDList((PCIDLIST_ABSOLUTE) pathData, ...);`.

That being said, that ComDlg32 key is undocumented and I don't think it stores a pidl so even if your code is corrected it is not going to work.

[`EnumMRUListW`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/shell/enummrulist) is a documented function you can call but it is not going to help you decode the data.

It looks to me like the location might be prefixed with the name of the .exe so as a minimum you would have to skip `(lstrlenW(pathData)+1)*2` bytes before you find the real data...

Comment: Thank you very much (the others too, but this helps me a lot). Actually, It was a typo. In the original code, this variable was dynamically allocated to handle errors such as ``ERROR_MORE_DATA``, and it seems that I forgot to remove the * character.
After a lot of work, ``SHGetPathFromIDList`` finally doesn't return ``FALSE`` anymore, and the program can successfully run without throwing an exception. However, the specified path is indeed not valid (Though, according to Microsoft's website, it should have retrieved something, well..). I'll update my question to add more informations.

Answer (score 0):

If you're going for undocumented stuff, here is a code that can dump an MRU list like the `LastVisitedPidlMRU` one:

```
// the Shell object that can read MRU lists
static GUID CLSID_MruLongList = { 0x53bd6b4e,0x3780,0x4693,{0xaf,0xc3,0x71,0x61,0xc2,0xf3,0xee,0x9c} };

typedef enum MRULISTF
{
  MRULISTF_USE_MEMCMP = 0x0,
  MRULISTF_USE_STRCMPIW = 0x1,
  MRULISTF_USE_STRCMPW = 0x2,
  MRULISTF_USE_ILISEQUAL = 0x3,
};

typedef int (__stdcall *MRUDATALISTCOMPARE)(const BYTE*, const BYTE*, int);

MIDL_INTERFACE("00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000") // unknown guid but we don't care
IMruDataCompare : public IUnknown
{
public:
  virtual HRESULT CompareItems(const BYTE*, int, const BYTE*, int) = 0;
};

MIDL_INTERFACE("d2c22919-91f5-4284-8807-58a2d64e561c")
IMruDataList2 : public IUnknown
{
public:
  virtual HRESULT InitData(UINT uMax, MRULISTF flags, HKEY hKey, LPCWSTR pszSubKey, MRUDATALISTCOMPARE pfnCompare) = 0;
  virtual HRESULT AddData(const BYTE* pData, DWORD cbData, DWORD* pdwSlot) = 0;
  virtual HRESULT InsertData(const BYTE*, DWORD cbData, int* piIndex, DWORD* pdwSlot) = 0;
  virtual HRESULT FindData(const BYTE* pData, DWORD cbData, int* piIndex) = 0;
  virtual HRESULT GetData(int iIndex, BYTE* pData, DWORD cbData) = 0;
  virtual HRESULT QueryInfo(int iIndex, DWORD* pdwSlot, DWORD* pcbData) = 0;
  virtual HRESULT Delete(int iIndex) = 0;
  virtual HRESULT InitData2(UINT uMax, MRULISTF flags, HKEY hKey, LPCWSTR pszSubKey, IMruDataCompare* pfnCompare) = 0;
};

int main()
{
  CoInitialize(NULL);
  {
    CComPtr<IMruDataList2> mru;
    if (SUCCEEDED(mru.CoCreateInstance(CLSID_MruLongList)))
    {
      const int max = 100; // get max 100 entries
      mru->InitData(max, MRULISTF_USE_MEMCMP, HKEY_CURRENT_USER, L"Software\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\Explorer\\ComDlg32\\LastVisitedPidlMRU\\", nullptr);
      for (auto i = 0; i < max; i++)
      {
        DWORD slot;
        DWORD size;
        // get size
        if (FAILED(mru->QueryInfo(i, &slot, &size)))
          continue;

        // get data
        // note beginning is a LPWSTR containing exe data
        auto data = (LPBYTE)_alloca(size);
        if (FAILED(mru->GetData(i, data, size)))
          continue;

        // the rest is a PIDL
        auto pidl = (LPCITEMIDLIST)(data + (lstrlen((LPWSTR)data) + 1) * 2);

        // get the shell item
        CComPtr<IShellItem> item;
        if (SUCCEEDED(SHCreateItemFromIDList(pidl, IID_PPV_ARGS(&item))))
        {
          // get its path
          CComHeapPtr<WCHAR> path;
          item->GetDisplayName(SIGDN::SIGDN_DESKTOPABSOLUTEPARSING, &path);
          wprintf(L"Executable: %s LastVisited: %s\n", data, path);
        }
      }
    }
  }
  CoUninitialize();
}
```

PS: I'm using [ATL's smart classes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/atl/reference/ccomptr-class)

Comment: How is this different than the documented EnumMRUListW?

Comment: It is different insofar as it uses undocumented COM classes and interfaces. I'm not sure this is any better or worse than [`EnumMRUListW`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/shell/enummrulist), which comes with the following disclaimer *"It might be altered or unavailable in subsequent versions of Windows."*

Comment: @Anders - EnumMRUListW (provided by Common Controls) doesn't work on Extended MRU Lists such as LastVisitedPidlMRU which read an MRUListEx registry key (provided by Windows Storage).

Answer (score 0):

I finally figured out how to create an `ITEMIDLIST` structure, and it all works well.

**Explanations**:

After some test, I've concluded that this value is not necessarily updated. The application that uses a file picker needs to write to the registry to reflect changes.
For example, VS Community 2022 / VS Code updates this value, but the new Microsoft Notepad does not (not sure for the old one). Apparently, .NET applications seem to be updated automatically, though.

First, we obviously must open the key at `Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\ComDlg32\LastVisitedPidlMRU`.
The stored data value we need is on one of the values, which has a number as a name.
The first byte of the `MRUListEx` value lies the last path.

```cpp
HKEY hKey = NULL;
std::wstring regMRUPath = LR"(Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\ComDlg32\LastVisitedPidlMRU\)";
LSTATUS statusCode = RegOpenKeyExW(HKEY_CURRENT_USER, regMRUPath.data(), 0, KEY_QUERY_VALUE, &hKey);
if (statusCode != ERROR_SUCCESS)
  // Handle error   
BYTE data[MAX_PATH];
DWORD bufferSize = MAX_PATH;
statusCode = RegGetValueW(hKey, L"", L"MRUListEx", RRF_RT_REG_BINARY, NULL, &data, &bufferSize);
if (statusCode != ERROR_SUCCESS)
   // Handle error
std::wstring keyName = std::to_wstring(data[0]);
```

Now that we have the value, we can get its data.

```cpp
DWORD reqBuffSize = 0;
statusCode = RegQueryValueExW(hKey, keyName.data(), NULL, NULL, NULL, &reqBuffSize);
if (statusCode != ERROR_SUCCESS)
   // maybe the specified key is invalid or missing.
BYTE pathData[reqBuffSize];
statusCode = RegGetValueW(hKey, L"", keyName.data(), RRF_RT_REG_BINARY, NULL, &pathData, &reqBuffSize);
if (statusCode != ERROR_SUCCESS)
   // maybe the specified key is invalid or missing.
```

We have another problem: The path is not directly accessible. The executable name is prefixed from the real path, so we must remove it.
Actually, it's very easy. The delimiter between the executable name and the real path is `\0\0\0`.

```cpp
const size_t offset = (lstrlenW(reinterpret_cast<LPCWSTR>(pathData)) * sizeof(wchar_t)) 
                      + (2 * sizeof(wchar_t));
```

The obtained value is not human-readable, but it actually stores a PIDL, so we can get it with `SHGetPathFromIDList`. The ITEMIDList is not very well documented on the Microsoft's website, but here's a way to create one of these things:

```cpp
IMalloc* pMalloc;
if (FAILED(SHGetMalloc(&pMalloc)))
    // handle error, failed to get a pointer to the IMalloc interface.
PIDLIST_ABSOLUTE pIdl = (PIDLIST_ABSOLUTE)pMalloc->Alloc((reqBuffSize - offset) + 1);
pIdl->mkid.cb = (sizeof(USHORT) + (reqBuffSize - offset));
memcpy_s(pIdl->mkid.abID, (reqBuffSize - offset) + 1, pathData + offset, (reqBuffSize - offset) + 1);
PIDLIST_ABSOLUTE pNext = ILGetNext(pIdl);
if (!pNext)
    // handle error, failed to get a pointer to the next item
pNext->mkid.cb = 0;
initialDir.reserve(MAX_PATH * 2);
```

The ITEMIDList structure has two members: cb and abID. cb is the size of a USHORT + the size of the data, and abID is a pointer to the data itself.
The last ITEMIDList struct must have cb set to zero to mark the end. ILGetNext gives us a pointer to the next element.

```cpp
// Finally, return the path!
std::wstring retValue;
retValue.reserve(MAX_PATH);
if (FALSE == SHGetPathFromIDList(pIdl, initialDir.data())) {
    // oh no! free the allocated memory and throw an exception
}
pMalloc->Free(pIdl);
```

It's not as hard as it seems to be at the beginning, but if you want to get this value for use with a file picker, it's recommended to use COM instead since it's easier and less error-prone. Thank tou all for tour response and have a good day!

If you want to get the path from a specified extension, see the `OpenSavePidlMRU` key. It works the same, but it requires some little adjustments.